# How can bcrypt.js know that the hashed password is the same as the plain text password?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt, security

I don't understand how the function that returns true or false can actually know that the hashed password is the same or not. If a person with a paper and a pen want to compare a plain text to a hashed text, he must know the salt of the hashed text. However no salt is needed to make the function of comparing passwords work.

The code goes like this:

```js
var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
var hash = bcrypt.hashSync("ilikepotatoes", salt);
```

and then the function for comparing is:

```js
bcrypt.compareSync("ilikepotatoes", hash);
```

So how does Node.js actually know what salt I'm using?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [the Wikipedia article on bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt):

> A bcrypt hash string is of the form:
>
> ```
> $2b$[cost]$[22 character salt][31 character hash]
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> $2a$10$N9qo8uLOickgx2ZMRZoMyeIjZAgcfl7p92ldGxad68LJZdL17lhWy
> \__/\/ \____________________/\_____________________________/
>  Alg Cost      Salt                        Hash
> ```

It knows the salt you are using because it is stored with the hash.

Comment: So Quentin. ¿Would you want to save the Salt of each user in a database? apart from the hashed password

Comment: Yes. You need to know the salt so you can compare hashed passwords. It doesn't matter if the salt is known, just so long as the salt isn't always the same (since that makes it vulnerable to rainbow tables). You don't need to *explicitly* save it, it is just part of the output from `bcrypt.hashSync`